# Custom annotation on test

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have some test that need Spring context to run:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Rollback
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeTest() {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }

}
```

I have created custom annotation for test:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Rollback
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public @interface DBTest {
}
```

Now - when i use @DBTest annotation on my test:

```
@DBTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }

}
```

In this case Spring context was not started.
How can I start that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) in your SomeTest class annotations. In order to apply the annotations you need spring to analyse them. But since your RunWith is not on your class, jUnit framework doesn't start spring, which, in turn, doesn't analyse the annotations.

Comment: On your class, not on the annotation